# How do i pull code from another branch on my github repository

Tags: git, github, git-pull

Ok, I had some challenges with my system and then decided to format it. comin g back, I would like to continue with my project and I would like to pull it from another branch(master)
I tried `git pull blog master` That didn't work. I need help in pulling from master rather it just pulled from main.

Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score -1):

You need to go like this.

```
git remote -v
```

To check out the remote where you are linked right now.
If the above command gives you "origin" as output, you can pull your branch using.

```
git pull origin master
```

If the output is not the origin, just use whatever your remote linked-to in place of origin.